# Opening an excel file with different numeric format

Tags: excel

I have a .xls file with the following content:

```
<table cellspacing="0" rules="all" border="1" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
<tr>
    <td>50,000000</td><td>NOrth Korea</td><td>A41F7271E99D</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

The problem I'm having is with the "50,000000" format. This number is supposed to be read as "50", but if the windows is configured with "." as decimal separator, then the number will be read as "50000000".

Is there a way to open the file in excel considering "," as decimal separator, even if the Windows is configured as "."?

Comment: This [document](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/import-or-export-text-files-HP001130599.aspx#_Toc289084174) might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is inside the "excel options"/"advanced". 
Uncheck the "Use System Separators", then the desired separators can be defined.